# Quite a simple one hopefully: Can .each() use an already defined function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, Is there a way this could work?

```
function resizer() {
    $(".rezimg").each(sizing($(".rezimg")))
    }
function sizing(im) {
    im.css({"width": "auto", "height": "auto"});
    var imight = im.height();
    var imidth = im.width();
    var idth = im.parent().width();
    var ight = im.parent().height();
    var aspecti = (imight/imidth);
    var aspectc = (ight/idth);
    if (aspectc>aspecti){
        im.css({"width": idth+"px", "height": "auto"})
    }
    else if(aspectc<aspecti){
        im.css({"height": ight+"px", "width": "auto"});
    }
    else if(aspectc==aspecti){
        im.css({"width": idth+"px", "height": ight+"px"});
    }
}
```

I hope my intention is clear here. sizing() is a function that compares the height of an image to a container and fits it accordingly. I want to use it at different points throughout my code. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, but it needs some changes. The following should work:

```
function resizer() {
    // notice that sizing is not a function call, but a reference
    $(".rezimg").each(sizing)
}

// should also be possible to call it directly on an element
function sizing(im) {
    // jQuery each sets the first argument to a number, otherwise it's an element
    var im = (typeof im === 'number') ? $(this) : im;

    im.css({"width": "auto", "height": "auto"});
    var imight = im.height();
    var imidth = im.width();
    var idth = im.parent().width();
    var ight = im.parent().height();
    var aspecti = (imight/imidth);
    var aspectc = (ight/idth);
    if (aspectc>aspecti){
        im.css({"width": idth+"px", "height": "auto"})
    }
    else if(aspectc<aspecti){
        im.css({"height": ight+"px", "width": "auto"});
    }
    else if(aspectc==aspecti){
        im.css({"width": idth+"px", "height": ight+"px"});
    }
}
```

Comment: The second argument to the foreach should give you the element.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder I know, but 'this' also refers to that element and this way you can also call the function on an element, not only in a foreach loop

Comment: Cheers mate, very helpful! I would have come a cropper on the each loop as well had it not been for your info.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify sizing as the function parameter. The argument will be `this`, which is the dom element represented by a ".rezimg". [See the docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for more info.

```
function resizer() {
   $(".rezimg").each(sizing)
}

function sizing(el) {
    var im = $(el);
    im.css({"width": "auto", "height": "auto"});
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote:

```
$(".rezimg").each(sizing($(".rezimg")))
```

Executes directly the function `sizing()` with the `$(".rezimg")` argument. But it won't be executed when `each` will, because `each` requires a function as parameter and `sizing($(".rezimg"))` is not a function (it is actually `undefined` as `sizing()` returns nothing).

You have to say to `each` what function it needs to execute, and with what parameter. You can do that with:

```
$(".rezimg").each(sizing.pass($(".rezimg")))
```

As `sizing.pass($(".rezimg"))` returns a pre-formated function with the parameter you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there's a couple of ways. You could call sizing and change the arguments on sizing to accept the index and the image element like below.

```
function resizer() {
    $(".rezimg").each(sizing); 
}
function sizing(index, img) {
    im.css({"width": "auto", "height": "auto"});
    var imight = im.height();
    var imidth = im.width();
    var idth = im.parent().width();
    var ight = im.parent().height();
    var aspecti = (imight/imidth);
    var aspectc = (ight/idth);
    if (aspectc>aspecti){
        im.css({"width": idth+"px", "height": "auto"})
    }
    else if(aspectc<aspecti){
        im.css({"height": ight+"px", "width": "auto"});
    }
    else if(aspectc==aspecti){
        im.css({"width": idth+"px", "height": ight+"px"});
    }
}
```

Or you could reference the current element being iterated over using `$(this)` within the sizing function i.e

```
 function resizer() {
    $(".rezimg").each(sizing)
}

function sizing() {
    var im = $(this);
    im.css({"width": "auto", "height": "auto"});
    var imight = im.height();
    var imidth = im.width();
    var idth = im.parent().width();
    var ight = im.parent().height();
    var aspecti = (imight/imidth);
    var aspectc = (ight/idth);
    if (aspectc>aspecti){
        im.css({"width": idth+"px", "height": "auto"})
    }
    else if(aspectc<aspecti){
        im.css({"height": ight+"px", "width": "auto"});
    }
    else if(aspectc==aspecti){
        im.css({"width": idth+"px", "height": ight+"px"});
    }
}
```